# Let $G$ be a group of order $pm$ where $p$ is prime and $p> m$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have to show that $G$ has a normal subgroup of order $p$. I have an idea: By the Cauchy theorem as $p$ divides to the order of $G$, then exits $H\in G$ such that the order of $H$ is $p$ and just need to see that $H$ is normal but i don't know how to see that or if someone has an other idea, thanks!

Comment: Are you allowed to use Sylow's theorems?

Comment: Yes, i can use Sylow's theorems

Answer (score 1):

There exists a Sylow subgroup of order $p$ say $H$, and the numbers of Sylow subgroups $n_p=1$ mod p. Suppose that there are at least $p+1$ Sylow subgroups, since for two different $p$-subgroups  $H,H'$, $H\cap H'=\{1\}$ since their cardinal is $p$, we deduce that $G$ has at least $(p-1)(p+1)+1=p^2$   elements; contradiction.
There is one Sylow $p$-group since all the Sylow subgroups are conjugated, we deduce that $H$ is normal.

Comment: yes, read the comments

Comment: One always should read comments :o) I'll remove my own.

Comment: Why are you only using half the information conferred by the Sylow theorems? You also know that $n_{p}$ divides $m$, whence the condition $m < p$ implies that $n_{p} = 1$, since $1$ is the only positive integer less than $p$ which is congruent to $1$ mod $p$.

Comment: Though your last assertion ends up being true, Sylow's Theorem actually says that any **two** $p$-subgroups are conjugate. I don't know if making them equal would be considered a valid proof (I'd at least be somewhat reluctant to accept it at face value).

Answer (score 0):

By the Third Sylow Theorem, you have $n_p$ Sylow $p$-subgroups, where $n_p\vert m$ and $n_p\equiv 1 \ (\text{mod}\ {p})$. Thus $n_p=qp+1$ for some $q\in\mathbb{N}$. But since $p>m$, you must have $q=0$. If not, you'd have $n_p>p>m$, but Sylow's Theorem asserts that $n_p|m$ and then $n_p<m$. So, you have $n_p=1$.

Since you have only one Sylow $p$-subgroup, it must be normal. Indeed, $n_p=[G:N_G(H)]=\frac{|G|}{|N_G(H)|}=1$, where $N_G(H)$ is the normalizer of the Sylow $p$-subgroup $H$ in $G$. Thus, $N_G(H)=G$, which means $H\unlhd G$.

Answer (score 0):

Group of prime order $p$ are cyclic. Let $k$ be number of such groups. Then there will be $k(p-1)$ elements of order $p$ in these subgroups. Then, McKay's proof of Cauchy's theorem gives, $k(p-1) \equiv -1 (mod p)$.

$k(p-1) + 1 = Lp$ where $L$ s some integer. Then, $k-1 = kp - Lp$. So, $p \mid k-1$.

Further,

$k(p-1) + 1 <= pm$

So, 
$k <= \frac{pm-1}{p-1}<= p-\frac{1}{p-1}$. Hence, $k < p$.

This means, considering, $p \mid k-1$, $k=1$.

Hence the proof of uniquness.

Answer (score 0):

I attempts to give two proofs here, one based on Cauchy's theorem and induced representation on cosets, the other on Sylow theorem. I'm still new to group theory, so there might be some mistakes. Any correction and critisism will be welcome. Please don't merely vote down.

**Proof 1:**

By Cauchy's theorem, $G$ has a subgroup $H$ of order $p$. Consider the representation induced by left multiplication on cosets of $H$, we denote by $\rho: G \to S_m$. For any $g \in \ker \rho$, we have $\,gH=H$, so $g \in H$ and $\ker \rho \leq H$.

Because $H$ is of prime order, by Lagrange's theorem we know either $\ker \rho = H$ or $\ker \rho = {1}$. We are done if $H = \ker \rho$, for $\ker \rho$ is a normal subgroup of $G$. Otherwise, $\rho$ is injective and $G \cong {\rm im} \, \rho \leq S_m$. It follows that $$pm=|G|\,|\,|S_m|=m!,$$ so $p$ must divide one of $l,1\lt l \lt m$, contradicting $p>m$.

**Proof 2**

By Sylow theorem, there exists some Sylow $p$-subgroup $H$ of $G$, which has  order $p$. Since $H \lhd G$ iff $H$ is the only Sylow $p$-subgroup, it suffices to prove the later argument.

Suppose that there is another Sylow $p$-subgroup $K$ of $G$. So there must be some element $k \in K$ with $k \notin H$. Consider the cosets
$$\{k^nH,\,n=0,\dots,p-1\}.$$
We show that any two of them are different.
If $k^{n_1}H=k^{n_2}H$ for some $0 \leq n_1<n_2 \leq p-1$, we have $k^{n_2-n_1} \in H$. Because $k^{n_2-n_1} \neq 1$, and any such element generates the whole cyclic group $K$ (because it has prime order), we deduce
$$K=\,<k^{n_2-n_1}>\, \leq H,$$
which is a contradiction to $k \notin H$. Hence, any two of the cosets are not the same, and there are $p$ different cosets, each containing $p$ elements. Therefore, we have at least $p^2$ different elements of the form $k^nh \in G$ where $h \in H$, contradicting $|G|=pm \lt p^2$.